# TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len() - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I still have this error on another part of the code:

```
class invoice(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.invoice"

@api.multi
def send_xml_file(self):
    # haciendolo para efacturadelsur solamente por ahora
    host = 'https://www.efacturadelsur.cl'
    post = '/ws/DTE.asmx' # HTTP/1.1
    url = host + post
    _logger.info('URL to be used %s' % url)
    # client = Client(url)
    # _logger.info(client)
    _logger.info('len (como viene): %s' % len(self.sii_xml_request))

    response = pool.urlopen('POST', url, headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml',
        'charset': 'utf-8',
        'Content-Length': len(
            self.sii_xml_request)}, body=self.sii_xml_request)

    _logger.info(response.status)
    _logger.info(response.data)
    self.sii_xml_response = response.data
    self.sii_result = 'Enviado'
```

Before in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113494/typeerror-object-of-type-bool-has-no-len-odoo-v9) the error was solved on this line:

```
_logger.info('len (como viene): %s' % (len(self.sii_xml_request) if self.sii_xml_request else '')
```

Now I have it again on the next one, I've tried with a conditional like before, but I still can't solve it, must be related to syntax or something, the error is on this sentence:

```
        response = pool.urlopen('POST', url, headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml',
        'charset': 'utf-8',
        'Content-Length': len(
            self.sii_xml_request)}, body=self.sii_xml_request)
```

Specifically on `self.sii_xml_request)}, body=self.sii_xml_request)` there's the `sii_xml_request` object again, I think is just a matter to add the conditional, since the field is empty...

But I still can't make it work properly, is this solvable in a similar fashion as my previous question?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

It is not a duplicate since this is another line of code, and a very very similar way to solve it won't apply here, it is a slightly different syntax.

**SECOND EDIT**

This is how it looks right now, the conditional is on every `len` of this function

```
@api.multi
def send_xml_file(self):
    # haciendolo para efacturadelsur solamente por ahora
    host = 'https://www.efacturadelsur.cl'
    post = '/ws/DTE.asmx' # HTTP/1.1
    url = host + post
    _logger.info('URL to be used %s' % url)
    # client = Client(url)
    # _logger.info(client)
    _logger.info('len (como viene): %s' % len(self.sii_xml_request)if self.sii_xml_request else '')
    #if self.sii_xml_request:
    response = pool.urlopen('POST', url, headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml',
        'charset': 'utf-8',
        'Content-Length': (len(
            self.sii_xml_request) if self.sii_xml_request else '')}, body=self.sii_xml_request)
    #else ''(len(self.sii_xml_request) if self.sii_xml_request else '') 

    _logger.info(response.status)
    _logger.info(response.data)
    self.sii_xml_response = response.data
    self.sii_result = 'Enviado'
```

Comment: Can you show your definition for `self.sii_xml_request`. When this error is raised it is because that attribute is returning `True` or `False` and you are trying to call `len()` on it which doesn't work for booleans. You need to make sure that `self.sii_xml_request` always returns a string (if that is what you want it to return)

Comment: (New comment because old one is too old to edit). `(len(self.sii_xml_request) if self.sii_xml_request else '')` would probably work in this case too, but ONLY if `self.sii_xml_request` returns `False`; if it ever returns `True` it will fail in the same way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len() - Odoo v9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113494/typeerror-object-of-type-bool-has-no-len-odoo-v9)

Comment: Hi, no, it is not a duplicate, it is another case, similar though, ok, let me try, Thank You

Comment: Hi, no, it doesn't work , gosh, it's really weird...

Comment: Same error :(    ...

Comment: Did you change it in every place where you are calling `len()` of that object? You will need to do that for sure.

Comment: @elethan yes, I've edited my question with the current code, the error comes on 'response' line

Comment: Post your stack trace please

Answer (score 1):

To avoid dragging on the conversation in the comments, I am going to take a crack at an actual answer.

It seems like your object `self.sii_xml_request` can be either a). a string, or b). a boolean (`True` or `False`) (though please correct me if I am wrong).

You are getting an error, because you are trying to take the `len()` of that object to get an idea of the length of the request, but when that object is `True` or `False` this will fail, because `bool` objects don't have a `__len__` attribute. You tried solving this based on a previous question by doing this instead:

```
(len(self.sii_xml_request) if self.sii_xml_request else '')
```

This will only work if `self.sii_xml_request` only ever returns a string or `False` (or something that is equivalent to `False` like `None` or `0` or `[]`, etc.), because if it returns `True`, then it will once again try to get the `len()` of the object which doesn't work.

Doing:

```
(len(self.sii_xml_request) if self.sii_xml_request is not True or False else '')
```

Might work, but I don't know what decides whether `self.sii_xml_request` returns `True`, `False` or some string, and you may want to handle `True` and `False` differently. Also, you probably never want to have content length be `''` because it will normally be an integer, so if anything you should have it be `0` if `self.sii_xml_request` is `False`. If you want to handle them the same try what I have above. Otherwise, you could define a variable `content_length` earlier, and set it accordingly based on the value of `self.sii_xml_request`. For example:

```
if isinstance(self.sii_xml_request, bool):
    content_lengthj == int(self.sii_xml_request)  # 1 if True else 0
else:
    content_length = len(self.sii_xml_request)

...
response = pool.urlopen('POST', url, headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml',
        'charset': 'utf-8',
        'Content-Length': content_length}, body=self.sii_xml_request)
```

Comment: Thank You elethan, but now, ´line 108, in send_xml_file
    response = pool.urlopen('POST', url, headers={
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()´ :''(

Comment: Going to try again, with first solution, sorry, I'll write back ASAP

Answer (score 1):

this kind of error when you get 'bool' in the message that means that you calling a function on an empty field so before you call any function check if the field has value first. because in odoo empty field contain False value not None i had this error many times every time i found out that i'm calling the function on an empty field